# Software Centre universe

Tags: package-management, software-center

Hi All I've been trying to download software from the software centre and it keeps saying Use this Source instead of install. When I try clicking universe source it never installs and gives me an error. Im new to ubuntu. And am on a fresh install. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Check your Software & Updates control panel. Do you have the Universe repository enabled?

Comment: Yes I do have it enabled.

Comment: I also get a bunch of errors like this one. W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/partner/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 80]

Comment: Ah, 'vivid'. You seem to be running an unsupported release of Ubuntu. Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid) reached End Of Life two years ago, and the repositories closed. Consider installing a supported release of Ubuntu, available at http://downloads.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Use a newer release of Ubuntu.  Vivid has been End of Life for a ***VERY*** long time.